# How to choose the internet connection mode Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, connection, ethernet

I made an Android application that is used to exchange files with a pc.

The computer and the device are connected to the same network and everything worked very well.

But since I put a 4g sim card, the transfer is no longer done, does anyone know how to solve this problem?

There must be a way to force my application to use only ethernet connection?

**Permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**How I check connection:**

```
public static Boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = null;
    if (cm != null) {
        activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }
    boolean isEthernet = false;
    if (activeNetwork != null) {
        isEthernet = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET;
    }
    return activeNetwork != null &&
            activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting() && isEthernet;
}
```

**Main function:**

```
public void sendFilesInFolder(Boolean bool) {
    if (isConnected(MainActivity.this)) {
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        if (bool) progressBar = mProgressBarD;
        else progressBar = mProgressBarM;
        fileSender = new FileSender(prefs.getString("ip_adress", null),
                Integer.valueOf(prefs.getString("port_dest", null)),
                bool, colisageBase, progressBar);
        fileSender.execute();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.no_connection), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your code here and logcat also

Comment: have you tried disabling your data connection?

Comment: When i disable data connection, it works. But i want to do programmaticaly.